# Validating the Performance of a Random Forest Regressor for Non Linear data

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, random-forest, scikit-learn

The OOB score in SK learn Random Forest Regressor gives the R2 score.

Now, from what I know, R2 score is only valid for linear data.

How do I validate the score of my model if my Random forest model is for non linear data?

Comment: The model "wrapper" classes like `GridSearchCV` accept a `scoring` Parameter that allows you to change the scoring function. I presume it works when `oob_score=True`, although it might be useful to confirm as much and post the answer here.

Comment: Also, for the record this question belongs on Stackoverflow, and not here. For some reason I don't see the option to vote that it be moved, instead of just closed.

Answer (score 1):

[`RandomForestRegressor` man page](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html) explains that you get  `oob_prediction_`s for the training cases as well.

You can then calculate e.g. MSE as

```
((y - rfr.oob_prediction_)**2).sum() / y.size
```

Comment: However this won't work inside grid search, pipelines, etc.

Comment: @ssdecontrol: did you mean to say that in case of this training being part of a grid search there are more elegant solutions? I'd expect  `GridSearchCV` to use normal predictions on cases held out according to the cross validation scheme by the wrapper - so that is a rather different question: that way you evaluate via normal predictions.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to use OOB. In random forest bagging, we build each tree on part of data. Then we check r^2 in the remaining data not used to build data. So u should be able to use OOB.

Comment: But again my question is R2 parameter is for linear data but my data is non linear? Can't we get MSE ?